# Hibernate 4 NonUniqueObjectException Embedded ID

Tags: hibernate

If you migrate from hibernate 3.6 to 4.3, then you have the NonUniqueObjectException during the refresh of entity having a ManyToOne in the embeded Id, then you should take a look at the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the readRow of EntityLoadQueryDetails class
we have

```
if ( entityPersister.getIdentifierType().isComponentType()  ) {
     final ComponentType identifierType = (ComponentType) entityPersister.getIdentifierType();
     if ( !identifierType.isEmbedded() ) {
         addKeyManyToOnesToSession(
            context,
            identifierType,
            entityKey.getIdentifier()
                        );
                    }
}
```

if you check the code of ComponentType -> isEmbedded() you will find

```
@Override
public boolean isEmbedded() {
     return false; -->> that dosent make a sens !!
}
```

so i change it, even if its not the perfect solution to

```
@Override
public boolean isEmbedded() {
    return propertyNames.length>1;
}
```

This is fully working to me